# Doctrine: Count results returns more than get results

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

I have a doctrine query to return all my customers belonging to a particular shop. In total, 29 records are returned. However, if I run a count query, with almost identical DQL, I get a different number of results

**Query1** - Fetch Results:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c INNER JOIN c.shops cs WHERE cs.shop IN(2, 3)
```

Returns (using count() to count the number of records returned)

```
int(29)
```

**Query2** - Count Results:

```
SELECT count(c) FROM Customer c INNER JOIN c.shops cs WHERE cs.shop IN(2, 3)
```

Retruns:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [1]=> string(2) "36" } }
```

I cant seem to work out how that can be happening? Hopefully someone can help...

Comment: Incidentally, the fetch is correct, there are 29 unique customers assigned to those two shops. I am guessing the 36 includes duplicates but why would the same query return a different list?

Comment: How about a `count(*)` or `count(id)`?

Comment: count(id) returns the same result and you can't do count(*) in doctrine. It seems there's an implied DISTINCT somewhere that I didn't ask for...

Comment: It seems that only selecting a single field (c.id, or c.name) goes back to giving you 36. Suspecting this is a Doctrine "feature"

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to "GROUP BY(c)"

Answer (score 1):

You have to account for the situation where if you have the same customer with an association with two shops, in raw SQL land you will get 2 rows.

Doctrine accounts for this in the hydration step of returning your records i.e. `$qb->getQuery()->getResults()`, and returns you a result set that makes sense (rather than one with duplicates that you would have to handle manually).

You can best visualise this difference by echoing out the SQL that Doctrine generates from your query `$qb->getSQL()` and executing it via something like Phpmyadmin, MySQL Workbench or Sequel Pro - and comparing that with your result returned from `getResults()`